# Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination as attribute rather than custom html directive

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

Angular generally allows you to specify certain directives as either custom HTML tags or as attributes on a standard html tag or as classes to be included on a tag. Does angular UI Bootstrap Pagination follow these principles? If so, is there an example of specifying pagination as an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is in the [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/pagination.js#L87)

```
.directive('pagination', ['$parse', 'paginationConfig', function($parse, config) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
```

where `restrict: 'EA'` means the directive can be used both as an element and as an attribute.

As for an example, you can just edit the examples on their [demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) using the "edit in plunker link"

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYIuTcBu1WOcJdBZ7OKt?p=preview) for an edited example with the first pagination from their demo.

Answer (score 2):

works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vB2x6/2/)

the pagination directive restricted as EA

```
<div pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" page="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true"></div>
```